# C : Correct output in Xcode but not terminal

Tags: c, xcode, bit-manipulation

I am writing a function to output double whatever value is passed in but if it overflows positively output the highest possible integer and if it overflows negatively output the lowest possible integer. We are only allowed to use signed 32-bit integers. I cannot use any if statements, loops, etc. nor any not allowed operation. Allowed operations are: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Here are how it is called in the main method:

```
printf("Boundedmult should be 2: %d\n", boundedMult(0x00000001));
printf("Boundedmult should be 2147483647: %d\n", boundedMult(0x50000000));
printf("Boundedmult should be -2147483648: %d\n", boundedMult(0xA0000000));
```

On Xcode the output is:

```
Boundedmult should be 2: 2
Boundedmult should be 2147483647: 2147483647
Boundedmult should be -2147483648: -2147483648
```

On the terminal the output is:

```
Boundedmult should be 2: 2
Boundedmult should be 2147483647: -1610612735
Boundedmult should be -2147483648: 1073741824
```

Here is the boundedMult method:

```
int boundedMult(int x) {
    int x2 = x + x;
    int signBitX  = x >> 31;
    int signBitX2 = x2 >> 31;
    //If x=neg,x2=neg : 1   x=pos, x2=pos : 0   If overflowed x=neg, x2=pos : 0     x=pos, x2=neg :0
    int negOverflowCheck = signBitX & signBitX2;
    //If negOverflowCheck != signBitX, then neg overflow
    int negOverflow = negOverflowCheck & signBitX; //1 = no negative overflow

    //If x=neg,x2=neg : 1   x=pos, x2=pos : 0   If overflowed x=neg, x2=pos : 1     x=pos, x2=neg : 1
    int posOverflowCheck = signBitX | signBitX2;
    //If posOverflowCheck | signBitX = 1
    int posOverflow = posOverflowCheck | signBitX; //0 = no negative overflow

    int largeNeg = 1 << 31;
    int largePos = 0xFF;
    largePos = largePos | (largePos << 8) | (largePos << 16) | (largePos << 23);
    //If x is neg and negOverflow = false return result or if negOverflow = true return largest neg
    //Or if x is pos and posOverflow= false return result or if posOverflow = true return largest pos
    //I'm using true and false as in matching the comments above not C convention so for negOveflow 1 = false (no overflow) and for posOverflow 0 = false (no overflow)
    return ((~!!signBitX+1)&((~negOverflow & largeNeg)|(negOverflow & x2))) | ((~!signBitX+1)&((~posOverflow & x2)|(posOverflow & largePos)));
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Edit: I am using the gcc compiler in terminal

Comment: I got the correct result on terminal.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.2.1, and the output in terminal is correct.